# apply bootstrap theme globally using react styled-components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I've tried to search for examples showing how to import and use the bootstrap theme globally using styled-components but could only find samples showing styling of components (e.g. https://github.com/aichbauer/styled-bootstrap-components) or recreating the css in injectGlobal (e.g. https://medium.com/styled-components/styled-components-getting-started-c9818acbcbbd).

I can't quite put it all together so am asking what are the procedures to import the bootstrap css once so that settings like fonts, font sizes etc take effect globally.
I was thinking something like:

```
    injectGlobal`
  @import url(‘url.to.bootstrap.css ');

  /* Hopefully there is a solution where I don't have to recreate these 
     settings because its achieved by the above import
  body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  }
  */
`
```

**update:** This works as expected. Thanks Simon.

```
injectGlobal`
  @import url(‘https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');
`
```

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/xDae/styled-bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

Load the css with `import`:

```
import 'path/to/bootstrap.css'
```

Or like you mentioned with `@import`:

```
injectGlobal`
 @import url(‘https://path/to/bootstrap.css');
`
```

Maybe this article can help you out: 
https://dev.to/spences10/getting-started-with-styled-components---5c04

Comment: Just found this post https://spectrum.chat/thread/f756a0c6-fcc6-4dd1-ab1b-a7b1580f8cb3, From the answer I wasn't sure if the '@import url' worked as I hoping. Can you confirm it does. I'll also give this a try tomorrow to see. Thanks